# Forecast with Python - a tool to present results

Tags: python, forecasting

I'm new in forecast with Python. 
So far my team and me prepared a dataset and have been playing with forecasting orders using ARIMA and Prophet. Currently we are using a Jupiter notebook for this.
Now we are looking for a tool to present those plots to our managers in a proper way. 
What is a common tool to provide those graphs/plots to business/managers or any other end-users?
What do you use? 
How your result does look like?
I could found only Exploratory

Comment: This is off topic for this SE and this question will be closed - however take a look at [streamlit](https://streamlit.io)

Comment: Thank you and sorry for off topic